# Standard slide positions for notes above high C

Tags: technique, trombone, fingering

What are the standard / usual tenor trombone slide positions for notes above high C? None of the charts I have found online goes beyond C (e.g., below).

I managed to find D and E positions on my trombone by ear, which are rather "off" the standard 1-7 positions. So my guess is that it depends a lot on the trombone, the mouthpiece, the player and so on..., but is there any standard practice? advice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the charts at https://norlanbewley.com/bewleymusic/trombone-slide-position-chart/ and https://olemiss.edu/lowbrass/studio/fingeringcharts/tenorandbasstromboneposition.pdf...

| note | Norlan Bewliey position(s) | Ole Miss position(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 1, 3, 5 | 1, 3 |
| C#/Db | 2, 4, 5 | 2, 5 |
| D | 1, 3, 4 | 1, short 3, 4 |
| D#/Eb | 3, 2 | short 2, 3 |
| E | 2 | 2 |
| F | 1 | 1 |
| F#/Gb | 3 | short 3 |
| G | 2 | short 2 |
| G#/Ab | 3 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| A#/Bb | 1 | 1, 3 |
| B |  | 2 |
| C |  | 1, 3 |
| C#/Db |  | 2 |
| D |  | 1, short 3 |
| D#/Eb |  | short 2, 3 |
| E |  | 2 |
| F |  | 1 |